# How to select rows from a table when having a list of GUIDs?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a SELECT where I have multiple GUIDs that I use with an IN operator.
Why this query does not return all rows where Table1UID equals each item from @table1IDs?

```
DECLARE @table1IDs NVARCHAR(100)
SET @table1IDs  = 'b15f554f-90ad-4fab-b3ac-a27bc68f3b21, 72213eb7-1041-408c-9ea1-35a667285c9b'

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE Table1UID in (@table1IDs)
```

It only returns the row where ID is 'b15f554f-90ad-4fab-b3ac-a27bc68f3b21'.

Mention: type of Table1UID is UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

Comment: It is strange to have string-list of GUID-s - looks like wrong design. Why not simple ID-s (int)?

Comment: this query I want only for debugging purposes. We use GUID for primary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you stored the value is wrong i guess, do as below

```
declare @temp table(ID nvarchar(1000))
insert into @temp values('b15f554f-90ad-4fab-b3ac-a27bc68f3b21')
insert into @temp values('72213eb7-1041-408c-9ea1-35a667285c9b')

SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE Table1UID in (select ID from @temp)
```

Comment: Thanks. I chose your solution cause you were the first. Solution of Reza ArabQaeni is almost the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @QRY NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @QRY = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE Table1UID IN (' + @table1IDs + ')'

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QRY
```

**UPDATE**

If you are selecting dynamic values, use the below code and that will work

```
SELECT @table1IDs = COALESCE (@table1IDs + ',[' + YOURCOLUMN + ']', 
              '[' + YOURCOLUMN + ']')
               FROM    (SELECT DISTINCT YOURCOLUMN FROM YOURTABLE) PV  
               ORDER BY YOURCOLUMN
```

Comment: this solution is more useful. @alexa use variable for GUIDs list

Comment: Thanks. Your solution worked but when I tried to add another condition where I had another GUID column it returned me conversion  issues. However it works as standalone, though hard to maintain. Thanks.

Comment: If your values are dynamic and you are selecting the value from a column you can use the updated code @Alexa Adrian

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @table1IDs table(id uniqueidentifier)
insert into @table1IDs(id) values 
('b15f554f-90ad-4fab-b3ac-a27bc68f3b21')
,('72213eb7-1041-408c-9ea1-35a667285c9b')

select * from table1 where Table1UID in (select id from @table1IDs)
```

Answer (score -1):

`Split` the string into rows and use it in `where` clause

```
DECLARE @table1IDs NVARCHAR(100)
SET @table1IDs  = 'b15f554f-90ad-4fab-b3ac-a27bc68f3b21, 72213eb7-1041-408c-9ea1-35a667285c9b'


SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  Table1UID IN(SELECT Rtrim(Ltrim(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')))
                          FROM   (SELECT Cast ('<M>' + Replace(@table1IDs, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data) AS A
                                 CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a))
```